# Hidden questions and items per page

Tags: feature-request, ignored-tags

In my preferences I've chosen **Hide questions in your ignored tags**;
Now, is there a way to make the **Items per page** option not to count the hidden questions?

Let's say I have **powershell** in my ignored tags. If I've set **50 item per page** and there are **10 items with powershell tag**, then I'll see just **40 items**.

That behavior becomes inconvenient when you have a lot of ignored tags.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get more questions on front page when ignoring tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354873/get-more-questions-on-front-page-when-ignoring-tags)