# Get more questions on front page when ignoring tags

Tags: feature-request, filtering, ignored-tags, interesting-page

After finally starting to listen to the SO podcast<sup>(a)</sup>, I decided to take some advice and more intelligently select questions for answering.

To that end, I started marking my favourite tags and adding those I have little interest in to the ignore-list.

I figured this would basically allow me to answer more questions since the ones I'll see are my areas of interest.

However, the main question page still seems to *query* all the questions to get fifty (configurable, of course) results and then just removes those I've decided to ignore. This greatly improves my experience with only getting appropriate questions but, unfortunately, I often only see two or three questions on the page (I've been rather vicious with my ignore-list).

What are the chances of changing this behaviour so that you get to see fifty results *after* filtering has taken place?

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Hilarious stuff, by the way, especially Joel's rather pitiful attempts at an Oz accent :-)

Comment: Interesting. I have a pretty vicious ignore list, too, but I still see *lots* of questions on the "interesting" page. Perhaps it's because I have the [tag:c#] tag on my interesting list, and we get *lots* of those questions here. I agree, though, that server-side filtering would be nice to finally have, as opposed to the client-side filtering we currently get.

Comment: @Cody, that *is* interesting. I've been using the newest tab on https://stackoverflow.com/questions rather than interesting tab on https://stackoverflow.com. I see the latter has an absolute *bucketload* more questions, most of which are highlighted. So I guess I'll just use that. Thanks for the info, cheers.

Comment: I need to learn to make better questions. I asked the same a long time ago and I only got a couple of visits (and still no answers): https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276842/hidden-questions-and-items-per-page?noredirect=1#comment576907_276842