# When so many questions are hidden because of ignored tags

Tags: bug, search, ignored-tags

There must be the same question here in the meta somewhere but I couldn't find it.  So...

When a user searches on Stack Overflow, it shows up to 15, 30, or 50 results per page, depending on which one is selected.  However, when a user has "Ignored Tags" set in their [preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences), search results might have empty pages!

Here is an screen shot I got from searching `[py.test]` with some Windows related tags ignored.  Note that it's already in the third page and I don't see any results!

> [image: no results]

With this search criteria, I can only see one result when I changed to 50 per page.  I see page 4 when it's a page size of 50, so I should have at least 150 results.

Why not just simply exclude the ignored tags from the results?  It might make sense if I can dynamically change the results display by changing the preference of one of the tags, but it doesn't.  Yes, I changed it (ignore -> norm -> star) on some of the tags shown, but the display didn't change.

Checking my preference,  I had [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) in the ignore list.  So what I got were questions with [py.test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/py.test) without [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag on it.  That explains why I got so few results.  The suggested tags didn't help, either.

Do you consider this a UX bug?

Comment: I didn't know such a feature existed! Finally I can protect my eyes from PHP!

Comment: … said the C# guy.

Comment: @Nisarg whats wrong with the [tag:PrettyHardtoProgram] tag? :)

Comment: I believe ignored tags are applied client side (in the browser). So the server provides a pageful of results, but at client side all of them get hidden. Definitely not the best approach if you ask me.

Comment: I had the same question back in [2011](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76285/) and learned to live with it.

Comment: lxg ...said the JavaScript guy? (LOL!) C# > JS

Comment: "with this search _criterion_" "criteria" is plural. :) Or maybe you want "With these search criteria".

Comment: @Nisarg I also didn't know  such a feature existed!... Now I can protect my eyes from C#, javascript, html, css questions.

Comment: @Almo Wiktionary says that the form _criteria_ is sometimes used as a "singular form (as in _a criteria_, _this criteria_, and so on), with corresponding plural form _criterias_. In this use, it sometimes means “a single criterion”, sometimes “a set of criteria”."

Comment: Sounds wrong since ending it "a" is plural for several things. Wiktionary is being descriptive instead of prescriptive in this case. And yes I am a prescriptive grammarian. :D

Comment: This language feud calls for the mandatory [How to Save the Princess in 8 Programming Languages](https://www.toggl.com/programming-princess).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Design is always a trade-off. Here the trade-off is between UX and performance (which of course has an impact on UX...)

Ignored tags are processed client-side, as is briefly mentioned in [the FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251971), for the sake of performance. Having to apply a 'but without any of {this loooong list tags}' to every question list would, I suspect, destroy performance. So the trade off is decided in favour of doing it client side, and sometimes getting weird results.

There's [a feature request to do it server-side](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354873/get-more-questions-on-front-page-when-ignoring-tags), so you can go vote for that...

Comment: it doesn't explain why client side isn't properly doing the pagination without hidden results though...

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice to sort the suggested tags by "most hiding tags first"? So that I could see `python` in the suggested tag list instead of unrelated `visual-studio`?

Comment: @TJ, pagination is done server-side. The client receives a page of questions, then filters by ignored tags.

Comment: if(list.count() == 0) request next page

Comment: @Tschallacka: What is the "next page"? Did the user intend to see the subsequent page or the previous? That would depend on what page the user used to be on relative to the one they clicked on. If you go from page 4 to page 3, it shouldn't show you page 4 again. Even if you could make it work, you're still invoking more than one server query per user click.

Comment: Keep in mind that the preferences page has two radio buttons below the list of ignored tags - hide and grey-out. The OP must have "hide" selected.