# Show more questions when ignoring and hiding tags

Tags: feature-request

> I know that [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354873/get-more-questions-on-front-page-when-ignoring-tags) has been asked before, but because that linked question was asked over a year ago and didn't get any real attention I try it again.

---

I have a lot of tags that I don't want to worry about, so I ignore them and use the *hide question* option:

[image]

It's a really nice feature, but the only downside to this is, that I now have much fewer questions displayed, instead of the *normal* 15.

---

Can more questions be displayed at once when one chooses to ignore many popular tags?

Comment: The hiding of questions in your ignored tags takes place after the question list is populated (i.e., on the front-end). Computing custom lists for every user on the back-end is considered too expensive to do, IIRC.

Comment: @HereticMonkey They could possibly just send through more questions before filtering.

Comment: You mean "instead of the normal **50**"? If 15 shows too few questions, you can just increase it to 30 or 50. Or is there a page which shows 15 and can't be changed?

Comment: @Dukeling Then you've got the problem of pagination; you've have to send back how many were displayed (and which) in order to get the next page's worth of questions, and you end up computing custom lists on the back-end again. I'm not saying it's a great way of doing this, but that's the reason I've heard in the past.

Comment: @HereticMonkey True, although simply adding a 100- or 200-question-per-page option (or just displaying all the questions post-filter) would trivialise that.

Comment: @Dukeling there would have to be some ceiling. I imagine that displaying the summary for millions of questions at one time on a page would give most consumer devices a run for their money.

Comment: But, if you figured out a reasonable ceiling, you could handle the pagination on the client side.

Comment: @TinyGiant My (one) idea is roughly: if, based on tags, you filter a lot of questions and choose the option to display 50 questions per page, they send through e.g. 100 instead of 50, and just display everything (which may show anywhere between 0 and 100, but typically no more than 50). Although this would require some complexity to keep it close to 50 (otherwise we can pretty much just replace it with a 100 option). Maybe client-side pagination would be simpler (although there would be some problems if you page non-sequentially).

Comment: `if (countAfterFilter < 80%) send20%MoreQuestionsNextTime(maxQuestions=200%); if (countAfterFilter > 120%) send20%LessQuestionsNextTime()`.